# Dependency Injection in .NET core layered services

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, repository-pattern

I'm trying to learn IoC and DI, and incorporate it into my layered webapi project on Asp.NET Core so that I can fake the database context using SQLite in-memory database and test the behavior of my service layers.

I have a few unitOfWorks each of which contains repositories. One Unit of Work per database. One of them looks like below:

```
public class GcgcUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{

    private readonly GcgcContext _context;
    public AssetRepository assetRepository;

    public GcgcUnitOfWork(GcgcContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        assetRepository = new AssetRepository(_context);
    }

    public int Complete()
    {
        try
        {
            return _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 0;
        }


    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

On My service layers, I use these unit Of Works. Some of the service classes interact with two different unit of works. Something like below:

```
public class GcgcService : IGcgcService
{

    public GcgcAssetDataDTO GetGcgcAssetData()
    {
        using (var uow = new GcgcUnitOfWork())
        using (var uowLandornet = new LandornetUnitOfWork())
        {
            var result = new GcgcAssetDataDTO();                                       
            /**do something.*/

            return result;
        }               
    }
}
```

But now, in order to test the behavior of the service layer, I will need to inject the repository with db context to the service layers constructors. So I need to change to something like below:

```
public class AssetService
{
  GcgcUnitOfWork _uow;
  LandornetUnitOfWork _uow2;

public AssetService(GcgcUnitOfWork uow, LandornetUnitOfWork uow2)
{
    _uow = uow;
    _uow2 = uow2;
}

public List<GcgcAsset> GetAssets()
{

    return _uow.assetRepository.GetAssets();
}

/*also use and interact with other service classes that use these unit of works as well*/
}
```

So that on my test project, I can instantiate service classes with unit of works with in-memory database db contexts. But how about the using statement? How I will take care of that? Anyone experienced a similar issue that I'm facing? Do you think that there is another, better way to architect the system?

Thank you and have a nice day

Comment: On your Complete method, you're returning 1 to indicate success, and 0 to indicate failure. Don't do that! You're losing valuable exception information! Let the exception bubble up to the point where the code can do something about with it. And remove the useless if block within your catch block.

Comment: The `GetGcgcAssetData` method creates `GcgcUnitOfWork` with a parameterless constructor, yet the `GcgcUnitOfWork` class as shown only has one constructor that takes an argument. That makes it difficult to understand what the question is. What does the code really look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but generally speaking, your repositories/units of work should implement an interface. Then, you'd inject only the interfaces. This allows you to then sub in different implementations for those interfaces in `ConfigureServices`.

However, there's a few key problems here. First and foremost, *do not* wrap your EF Core context in a repository/unit of work. EF is an ORM, and as such, it *already* implements the repository (`DbSet`) and unit of work (`DbContext`) patterns. If you were to take your own repositories and unit of work to their natural conclusions, implementing every bit of functionality possible, you would have done nothing but just recreated EF. When you use an ORM, like EF, you are in fact opting to use a third-party DAL, and as such, it makes no sense to create your own DAL layer in addition to that.

You may argue that you still want an abstraction over EF, but you already have that in your service classes. Those should utilize your context directly, and the repositories and unit of works should go in the trash.

Second, seeing something like `public AssetService(GcgcUnitOfWork uow, LandornetUnitOfWork uow2)` tells me instantly, that this class is broken. A unit of work is supposed to encapsulate an entire subdomain, if you're then injecting two of them, that means your service class is working with two different subdomains and is therefore doing too much. A class should do just one thing and do it well.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Using Repositories is a debatable subject.  I don't test the code in the data access layer. So I don't test repositories. In that case, I don't think that I need interfaces for the repository. What Im trying to accomplish is that I would like to pass those unit of work into my service layer, with a in-memory mock database, so that I can test the behaviour of the servica layer.

Comment: It's really not. The pattern exists soley to abstract persistence from the domain. EF already does that.

Comment: Let me put it in another way. I use repositories to separate db operations from the business logic. Instead of repository, I could use something like project.DATA.

Comment: The actual DB operations are abstracted by EF, which again has its own repository layer. If you're talking about the whole idea of persistence in general, that is covered by your service. In either case, your repository layer is a superfluous abstraction that only adds more maintenance and testing concerns with no benefit.

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry for getting back to you late on this. So the service layer is where stuff contains business logic. I thought about this, and I decided that it's not good idea to expose db context directly to the service layer. Of course, it depends on the context and project. But If I do, there will be a lot of code duplication and different services share the same db operations. So for that reason, it will be good idea to encapsulate dbcontext, no matter if its a repository or custom data class.

Comment: Services should not "share DB operations". A service should encapsulate your subdomain. If services are using the same entities and doing the same things, they shouldn't be different services.

Comment: Or more accurately, you should better delineate your subdomains.